# Lua countdown timer for months and years

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Below is an example of a countdown timer for Corona SDK written in LUA.
How would I add days, months and years to this?

```
local function updateTime()
-- decrement the number of seconds
secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1

-- time is tracked in seconds.  We need to convert it to minutes and seconds
local minutes = math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 )
local seconds = secondsLeft % 60

-- make it a string using string format.  
local timeDisplay = string.format( "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds )
clockText.text = timeDisplay
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Days (and hours) would be trivial, but what about months and years? Since you have no timestamp telling us of how many seconds left to what, it's hard knowing exactly how many months, depending on the length of the months (28, 29, 30 or 31 days). The same with years if we consider leap years as well. In any case, here's something that might be sufficient:

```
local SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60
local SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR
local SECONDS_IN_MONTH = 30 * SECONDS_IN_DAY -- assuming an average of 30 days per month
local SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 365 * SECONDS_IN_DAY

local years = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_YEAR) % 365)
local months = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_MONTH) % 12)
local days = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_DAY) % 30)
local hours = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_HOUR) % 24)
local minutes = math.floor((secondsLeft / 60) % 60)
local seconds = secondsLeft % 60
```

Comment: As an example I would want the countdown to start from a future custom date example , 01/04/2025 would show (8 Years, 11 Months, 10 Days, 11 Hours etc), To keep simple It does not have to be accurate to leap years and days in month (although I would like to add later)

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, I think my snippet of code is good enough for your use-case then.